# Salvar Arquivo em Caminho Físico

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagem, upload

Estou fazendo upload de uma imagem que recebo via form usando C# ASP.NET.
Meu código está funcionando assim:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        try
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string _FileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string _path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles"), _FileName);
                file.SaveAs(_path);
            }
            ViewBag.Message = "File Uploaded Successfully!!";
            return View();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "File upload failed!!";
            return View(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Mas o diretório que ele está salvando é virtual (pasta criada dentro do projeto). Eu consigo salvar essa imagem em um diretório físico (pasta que está em outro local que não seja dentro do projeto)?

Comment: Passe o local físico para sua string _path = "c:\\temp\\uploads\\" + fileName ;

Comment: Só se tiver permissão

Comment: Realmente dá erro de permissão. Será que consigo passar por esse bloqueio?

Comment: O diretório físico é sua maquina ou é um servidor externo de alguma empresa?

Comment: Servidor da empresa, mas na mesma máquina que está rodando a aplicação, mas em pasta que não pertence ao projeto, tipo c:\\imgTemporarias

Comment: O Servidor que está rodando a aplicação é o IIS? Se for tenta dar permissão na pasta local para o usuário IIS_IUSRS.

Comment: A pasta já tem permissão para o usuário IIS_IUSRS, mas agora está dando o erro O método SaveAs está configurado para exigir um caminho com raiz, e o caminho 'caminhoDoServidor\\nomeDaImagem' não tem raiz.

Comment: já tentou passar assim o caminho (@"C:\imgTemporarias\" +FileUpload1.FileName)

Comment: Dá o mesmo erro. Estou no ambiente de desenvolvimento, rodando a aplicação na minha máquina e enviando para o servidor que é outra máquina. Será que esse pode ser o problema?

Comment: O erro não é o ambiente não, tentei no ambiente de produção e dá erro também.